# Explaining how critical values relate to confidence intervals

Tags: self-study, hypothesis-testing, distributions, confidence-interval

I'm trying to get the logic behind confidence intervals straight in my head so I can effectively explain it. So far I have the following description:

> The sample mean I calculate will not match up exactly with the population mean. This is because of sampling error. However, I do have an idea of how variable our sample means can be because we can estimate standard error. This is equivalent to the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of sample means.
>
> Based on the Central Limit Theorem and rules the normal distribution, I know that approximately 95% of our sample means will be within 1.96 standard errors of the true population mean in our sampling distribution of the sample means. The critical value is 1 minus the confidence coefficient which I've set at 0.95.
>
> But this sampling distribution is a useful fiction. In practice I have a sample mean and a measure of standard error. I use the point estimate of the sample mean I have along with the critical value and standard error estimate (the latter 2 of which are know as the margin of error). This allows me to create a confidence interval around the point estimate.

I'm unsure of how to explain the move from the use of the 95% level on the sampling distribution to its use on the point estimate. I can write out an explanation but it's not yet intuitive to me. When I take one sample mean and draw a margin of error around it I visualise a new normal distribution that is shifted to the left or right of the sampling distribution of the sample mean but I'm not sure if that is accurate.

Comment: This seems clear enough to be answerable to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: @gung It's actually so clearly and well stated that it's difficult to see what else there might be to add to this explanation.  In sum, this question gives a wonderful account of confidence intervals and then complains that part of it is "not intuitive."  Addressing that seems to be a matter for a psychologist, not a statistician!

Comment: @whuber Haha! That's encouraging and worrying all in the same breath.

Comment: I really don't know what to say, except to encourage you to try to identify the point at which you might be confused a little more precisely.  Given the quality of your account of CIs, I rather suspect you're not confused at all , but only *think* you are!

Comment: @whuber, the motivation for that comment was that the thread had been flagged to be closed as *unclear*. I was stating for future reference that the thread need not be closed, IMO.